# Is the pageState dictionary accessible over all pages in a metro app or does each page have its own?

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I want to know if it's possible to access items saved in the pageState of one page, from a different page when that app is resumed.

For example:

page1:

```
    protected override void SaveState(Dictionary<String, Object> pageState)
    {
        pageState["blah"] = "example";
    }
```

Then in page2:

```
    protected async override void LoadState(Object navigationParameter, 
        Dictionary<String, Object> pageState)
    {
        String x = pageState["blah"];
    }
```

Will the above work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No.**

Each page **may or may not have** a dictionary of state saved during an earlier session. That state is **page specific data** that you saved when the app was terminated and you should use it to restore the page to the way it was when the user left it.